# Cancelling vscode warnning `Incorrect type. Expected "array"`

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I'm writing a `manifest.json` as instructed in the [google chrome extensions- getting started](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) and the manifest is working fine, but on vscode I'm getting the following error :
[image]

As said, it's working just fine despite of this warning, but I want it gone. Is there a way to cancel this error? Or, of course, is there a way to correct my code so it will not show warnings?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. This is caused by a VSCode Extension that is performing linting/providing validation. You will have to disable them one-by-one until you find the offending plugin. However the first place to start is Angular Snippets by John Papa. That was the plugin that was causing this error for me. Angular projects use manifest.json too like Chrome extensions do. Their schemas are inconsistent. You can disable the Plugin for the workspace that contains your Chrome Extension.

That way you keep the cool Angular Snippets for other projects but disable for your Chrome Extension,

Before disable. Notice the Problems in the workspace.
[image]

[image]

Then choose Disable (Workspace)
[image]

Then problem is gone.
[image]

(Separate Pro tip: Add json.schemas element to your settings.json for the vscode project to validate your manifest.json, like so.

```
"json.schemas": [{
        "fileMatch": ["../src/manifest.json"],
        "url": "http: //json.schemastore.org/chrome-manifest"
    }]
```